# If a TVS X has a countable local base, then X has a balanced local base $\{V_n\}$ such that $V_{n+1}+V_{n+1}+V_{n+1}+V_{n+1} \subset V_n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In Rudin's Functional analysis Theorem 1.24, he states without further explanation the following.

> If X is a topological vector space with a countable local bases, then X has a balanced local base $\{ V_n\}$ such that  $V_{n+1}+V_{n+1}+V_{n+1}+V_{n+1} \subset V_n \ \  n=1,2,3...$.

I am confused about the statement. Here is my thought.

---

Suppose $\{W_n\}$ is the countable local base. Given $W_1$, then there is a **balanced** neighborhood of $0$ belonging to $W_1$, by Theorem 1.14(a). We denote it by $V_1$.

Then by Theorem 1.10, there exists a symmetric neighborhood of $0$, $U_1$, such that $U_1 + U_1+U_1+U_1\subset V_1$. Then there exists $W_m$ such that $W_m\subset U_1$ since $\{W_m\}$ is the local base. Then there exists a **balanced** neighborhood of $0$ belonging to $W_m$, by Theorem 1.14(a) again, and we denote it by $V_2$.

We can do it recursively, and get the desired $V_n$.

---

But one key question in this construction is: will the resulting $\{V_n\}$ still be a local base for the space X?

Comment: Sure. Because $V_n\subseteq W_{m(n)}\subseteq W_n$ for suitable $m(n)\ge n$.